# Its possible that class take only the same variable type (int + int || string +string)

Tags: java

Its possible that class take only the same variable type (int + int || string +string). I use generics type and i don't know that is possible?

```
class Para1 <T> {
    private T value_1;
    private T value_2;

    public Para1(T value_1 , T value_2){
        this.value_1 = value_1;
        this.value_2 = value_2;
    }
    public void setValue_1(T value_1){
        this.value_1 = value_1;
    }
    public void setValue_2(T value_2){
        this.value_2 = value_2;
    }
    public T get_value_1(){
        return value_1;
    }
    public T getValue_2(){
        return  value_2;
    }
}

a1KlasaButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         Para1 p1 = new Para1<>(textArea1.getText(),textArea2.getText());
         textField1.setText(p1.get_value_1() + "\n" + p1.getValue_2());
         super.mouseClicked(e);
     }
});
```

Comment: When you want only one type at a time, then why do you use two different generic types? Just use one ...

Comment: yes, but i use string + int it s compile

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. Just use one generic parameter.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954009/can-i-create-a-generic-method-that-accepts-two-different-types-in-c-sharp

Comment: Did you edit the code of your question as an answer to the original question, or are you still having further problems after making that change?

Answer (score 0):

Of course - just define your class with a single generic type parameter:

```
public class Para2 <V> {
    private V value_1;
    private V value_2;

    public Para2(V value_1 , V value_2){
        this.value_1 = value_1;
        this.value_2 = value_2;
    }

    ...
}
```

...

```
Para2<String> p2 = new Para2<>(textArea1.getText(),textArea2.getText());
```

Comment: and i use string and integer its working it s must take two the same types

Comment: @sadasdaaaa It will take any number you wish of parameters of the same type. Using a single type parameter means that all the values you pass to your constructor must match the type you used in the declaration of `p2` (String in this example).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single type-argument for multiple members:

```
public class Para2 <K> {
    private K value_1;
    private K value_2; // Also uses K

    // all the methods are changed to fit this change
}
```

Note, btw, that you can't use a type argument to refer to a primitive type like `int` in Java. You'll have to use the wrapper class `Integer` instead.